# Why is my Avro code generated as an Interface, instead of a Class?

Tags: java, avro

I can't call the newBuilder() method on my Avro generated class.

```
      return (data -> {
        return Flux.fromIterable(data)
            .map(sampleRecord -> SampleRecord.newBuilder() // FAIL - avro supplied newBuilder() method not found
                .setId(1)
                .setDescription("desc")
                .setValue(42)
                .build())
            .collectList();
      });
```

When I look at the actual generated code, I can see the generated class is actually defined as an interface(!!), instead of a class which would then define newBuilder().

I am sure my .avdl code is valid!

```
@namespace("com.example")
protocol SampleRecord {

    record SampleRecord {
        string id;
        string description;
        string value;
    }
}
```

Why is it generating a SampleRecord interface, instead of a class?!

Answer (score 1):

The protocol, and the record name (the name of the would-be class) are the same. This (for some reason) indicates to the *.avdl parser that the record should be output as an interface. Rename the protocol so that it is unique. Then, the record will be generated as a class.

```
@namespace("com.example")
protocol SampleRecordProtocol {

    record SampleRecord {
        string id;
        string description;
        string value;
    }
}
```

Notice the protocol and record names are different.